# Why do reshape codes end in glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)?

Tags: opengl

When looking at the reshape examples in the redbook, I usually find something like:

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

I understand that calling `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` followed by `glLoadIdentity();` resets the projection matrix but I don't understand why `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` is usually called at the end of reshape.

In this particular example `glFrustum` affects the projection matrix, right? Why is `GL_MODELVIEW` called later? Would it make a difference if the last call to `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` is omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your rendering code is going to affect `GL_MODELVIEW`, because it's what affects object translation and camera position. However, the resizing code works on `GL_PROJECTION`. The programmer probably assumes the current matrix is the modelview one in most of his code, and when a different one needs to be affected, he/she would change the matrix, update it, and then change the target back to `GL_MODELVIEW` so the rest of the code doesn't target the wrong matrix.

Generally, OpenGL functions affect whatever matrix is currently being targeted, which is why you change the matrix.

Comment: Would it make a difference if the last call to glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) is omitted?

Comment: Yes - unless you'd put it somewhere else. Basically most of the matrix operations are done on modelview matrix (the projection matrix is only estabilished once per window resize... or even once per run), so you want the modelview matrix stack to be the active matrix stack (i.e. affected by all the matrix calls). That's why the trend is to "if you want to modify other matrix stack, then turn it on, do your stuff and revert back to modelview".